# Python copying files gives no output

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to copy and automatically moves files from one directory to another. I have the basic code and after testing if it recognizes the data and it does by printing out the file names. When I use the `shutil.move` it doesn't give me an output and it does not move the files.

I also want to be able to move files like this many times and I am trying to find a if statement for when a file exist for it to move on to the next file. Any Suggestions?

Forgive me for the xxx it is to cover up the file paths and names at work

However here is the code I have so far:

```
import os
import shutil

#Path to copy or move files from
path1 = r"C:xxx"

#Variable to list all the files in the directory
file_dir = os.listdir(path1)

#Test print to see if the directory can be accessed WORKED
#print(file_dir)

#variable for the files to be moved into whe they are moved/copied
fpath =  r"C:xxx"

#For loop so go through every file in the directory
for file in file_dir:
    #If statsment so the only files with .jpg will be moved
   if file.endswith('.jpg'):
    #Method to recursivly move each file 
    #path.join combines the two paths 
       shutil.move(os.path.join(file_dir,file), os.path.join(fpath, file))
```

My idea for the if staement:

```
if filename exist:
    go to the next file
else:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(file_dir,file), os.path.join(fpath, file))
```

Is there anyway to fix the files not moving and how to get this if statement to work.

Comment: The only thing I can see that would prevent files from being moves is if none of them end with `.jpg`.

Comment: is the .jpg part of the filename or is that the extension?

Comment: Extensions are part of the filename.

Comment: Be aware that endswith() is case sensitive. If you have .JPG files, this won't work. Try this: `filename.lower().endswith('.jpg')`

Comment: Any reason you're doing this in Python? This is a simple shell cmmand `mv srcdir/*.jpg destdir`

Comment: Thanks to you I figured out what's wrong. Thank you for your help. Any suggestions on the if statement.

Comment: You can solve the case problem with `if file.lower().endswith('.jpg')`

Comment: I am using python because that is what I am being told to work in. I actually did this in bash a while back however I need python for this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may accomplish what you are trying to achieve:

```py
import os
import shutil

# Path to copy or move files from
source = os.getcwd()
# Path to move/copy files to
destination = os.path.join(source, 'images')

# For loop so go through every file in the directory
for file in os.listdir(source):
    # If statement so only files with .jpg will be moved
    if file.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
        shutil.move(file, destination)
```

In the last line of your code, `file_dir` is a `list` (i.e.,  `os.listdir(path1)`). This is where you may be getting an error. You cannot use the `join()` function to concatenate `lists` & `strings.`

Comment: I see what I did wrong, Thank you :)